# Security issues with SQL Query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on an Oracle SQL query. The query is getting flagged by Fortify SCA for Privilege Management: Default Function or Procedure Rights. Can someone help me with the correct way of using the query?

The query I want to use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "reset_sequence"
IS
  l_value NUMBER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT "ordering_seq".nextval FROM dual' INTO l_value;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE "ordering_seq" INCREMENT BY -' || l_value || ' MINVALUE 0';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT "ordering_seq".nextval FROM dual' INTO l_value;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE "ordering_seq" INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0';
END;
```

Comment: Not familiar with the tool, but might it just be that you don't have [an `AUTHID` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/invokers_rights_clause.html#GUID-66745CF3-81D9-491B-BD49-E83E05A5C4E4)? (Though I'm tempted to joke that it's complaining about quoted identifiers *8-)

Comment: Fortify is advising you there is a potential issue with your code. I don't think the select ... into statements have be execute immediate nor the last alter sequence. I'm not sure you can mitigate the the first alter though. You don't mention the context of how this code is expected to execute nor what the implications are of not addressing the issue. Is is it sufficient to add this to a risk a register of known issues due to the limitations of the language?

Comment: On a side note: This is not a query, but a procedure. I changed the tag from `sql` to `plsql`. PL/SQL is Oracle's programming language you are using here.

Comment: Another side note: I wouldn't use quoted names in Oracle. Once you do this, names suddenly become case sensitive, which can confuse even experienced database programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the Fortify docs](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.structural.sql.privilege_management_default_package_rights):

> **Privilege Management: Default Package Rights**
>
> PLSQL/TSQL
>
> **Abstract**
>
> Packages without an `AUTHID` clause default to `AUTHID DEFINER`.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> PL/SQL packages can be either `AUTHID DEFINER` or `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`. Functions and procedures in a package with definer's rights execute under the privileges of the user that defines the package. This can allow updates and access to specific pieces of data without granting access to entire tables or schemas. In a package with invoker's rights, or `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`, functions and procedures execute under the privileges of the user who invokes them. This does not allow a user to gain access to data it didn't already have access to. If no `AUTHID` clause is provided, the package defaults to definer's rights.
>
> Packages are usually defined by SYS or another highly privileged user, making any exploits of the code potentially more dangerous.

So it seems you just need to add [an `AUTHID` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/invokers_rights_clause.html#GUID-66745CF3-81D9-491B-BD49-E83E05A5C4E4), even if that is just explicitly stating the default value again (though you should establish the correct value, of course).

---

Not relevant, but neither `select` needs to be dynamic - you may have chosen to do that so it looks more consistent with the `alter` statements, but it isn't necessary; and they don't even need to be selects any more - you could do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "reset_sequence"
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
  l_value NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_value := "ordering_seq".nextval;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE "ordering_seq" INCREMENT BY -' || l_value || ' MINVALUE 0';
  l_value := "ordering_seq".nextval;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE "ordering_seq" INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0';
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

I can spot a couple of issues here:

- There's no `authid` clause, so it defaults to `definer`
- `execute immediate` with string concatenation

This means anyone with execute privileges on the procedure is running with the full rights of the procedure owner. And with string concatenation, there's the risk of SQL injection. Yes, [even with numbers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34546/is-there-any-way-to-break-out-of-the-string-and-inject-sql-without-using-a-singl/34591#34591).

Also you can get the next value of a sequence by assigning it. No need for `execute immediate`.

To be safe, I'd make the following changes:

- Add `authid current_user`
- Explicitly `to_char` the increment, avoiding attacks on this

Giving:

```
create sequence ordering_seq
  start with 100;

select ordering_seq.nextval from dual;

NEXTVAL   
       100 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE reset_sequence
  authid current_user
IS
  l_value NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_value := ordering_seq.nextval;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE ordering_seq INCREMENT BY -' || 
     to_char ( l_value, 'TM', 'NLS_Numeric_Characters = ''.,''' ) || 
     ' MINVALUE 0';
  l_value := ordering_seq.nextval;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE ordering_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0';
END;
/

exec reset_sequence;

select ordering_seq.nextval from dual;

NEXTVAL   
         1
```

Of course, using invoker's rights means you have to give out `alter sequence` rights to whoever calls. Which brings its own issues. To overcome this you could use [Code-Based Access Control](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/code-based-access-control-12cr1).